# What is the common way to install utility programs like file and ripgrep in NixOS

Tags: nix, nixos, nixops

I want these programs to be installed in my user environment while not using nix-shell and nix-env (I was told to not use nix-env). I tried to use home-manager but I can't do program.file/ripgrep bc it's not an option. May I ask what is the common approach to install things like file and ripgrep in NixOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With home-manager, you can install programs by adding them by adding them in `home.packages`. For instance, if you want to install ripgrep, you could add in your `home.nix`:

```hs
home.packages = [
  pkgs.ripgrep
];
```

Or, more conveniently

```hs
home.packages = with pkgs; [
  ripgrep
];
```

You can add any program you want in that list.

---

Note that there is a difference between installing them with home-manager, and by adding it in `environment.systemPackages`, which is that the former will only install them for the user, while the latter will install system-wide. Besides that, both work similarly.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set this in your nixos config:

```
environment.systemPackages = [
  rigrep
  file
];
```

I have no experience with home-manager so I don't know how it compares, but you should surely be able to install ripgrep with it.

I've been using `nix-env` for years without issue, only negatives is it's harder to keep track of things. But works fine for things you want to install 'temporarily' to have them available in your $PATH without having to invoke nix-shell.